# Problem with GetTable Method in Linq 2 SQL

Tags: linq

Hi All
I write this code:

```
using (NWindDataContext context = new NWindDataContext())
{
  var table = context.GetTable<T>();
  return table.ToList();
}
```

and assign return value to a datagridview.the problem is when table has foreign key result value has reference to related tables and binding going to Exception.
How to get just columns of a table with generic method that accept T type and return columns of Corresponding Table.
thanks Alot

Comment: What is `T`? Please should the entire method/class, else the snippet you have is useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<T> SelectAll<T>() where T : class
        {
            try
            {
                using (NWindDataContext context = new NWindDataContext())
                {
                    var table = context.GetTable<T>();
                    return table.ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

and Use Of it:

```
public void UpdateDataGrid()
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Repository.SelectAll<Order>();
        }
```